# Generate a template with Html Webpack Plugin

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I want to generate a template with Html Webpack Plugin.  I don't want to generate an .html file from a template, I want to generate an .ejs template from another .ejs template.

I want to do this so that when rendering the template from the backend, I can insert different api keys depending on the environment.  For example, I want to generate a template that looks something like this:

```
...
<script>
   API.setKey('<%= APIKey %>');
</script>
...
```

so that when staging, a test key can be used.

Is it possible to generate templates with Html Webpack Plugin?

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say you want to render a .ejs template using another .ejs template, but you might want to check out `ejs-loader` to generate .ejs templates. [https://github.com/okonet/ejs-loader](https://github.com/okonet/ejs-loader)

Comment: I want to generate a template that still has <%= %>.  Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @cynicaldevil It was actually easy.  I just put the '<%= %>' into another template tag. `<%=  '<%= APIKey %>' %>`

Comment: @oorst thank you, it worked for me. The only thing to mention is you should escape the template characters in the string.
Ex:
`<%= '\<\%\= user_data \%\>' %>`

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md#2-setting-a-loader-directly-for-the-template)

You can override the loader:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({

  template: '!!html-loader!src/index.ejs'
})
```

it should be possible just to use an "identity-loader"

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can generate any text based file with this plugin. You will have to provide `template` and `filename` properties to the plugin as follows

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'template.ejs',
  filename: 'endresult.ejs'
})
```